# How do deploy IPhone app

Tags: iphone

I need to create an IPhone app as an alternative interface to our commercial application.  Our application is sold to Hospitals and installed at their location.  How do I distribute this IPhone app to the doctors that practice at the individual hospitals?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a separate Developer Account type for developing and distributing apps that are not distributed through the App Store.  The price is steeper ($299 instead of $99).

Details are on apple's site here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

Comment: That URL is rather overreaching, is there a more specific URL or can you provide help on where to look?

Comment: You are looking for the iPhone Developer Enterprise Program. It is issued to companies with more than 500 employees who wish to deploy an application in-house http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/distribute.html

Comment: I have looked at this but I am not deploying it in-house.  We are a ISV and want to deploy it to users of our software that is installed at hospitals.

Comment: It's probably worth getting in touch with Apple directly about this.  Your distribution scheme doesn't match either of the 2 standard ones available to the general public.  Apple may have some way to address special needs such as yours.

Answer (score 0):

you can use adhoc type under distribution deployment reference link is: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/my/distribution/index.action

Answer (score 0):

Use AdHoc distribution to compile a copy with a special provisioning profile that allows him to install it on his device through iTunes. AdHoc distribution allow you to share your application with up to 100 other iPhone or iPod touch users, and you can share your application through email or by posting it to a web site or server.